# Movable window in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have window which is now movable in the application but the issue is the window get move out of the context as well with in the context it get go behind the control and than the window is not reachable.

Please suggest the solution for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can try using [FloatableWindow](http://floatablewindow2.codeplex.com/) instead.  If you want to know *how* it works, the source code is public and I am sure you can find the answer looking through it.  I can say that it is normally pretty complex to get this working right with window resizing and all the other things you need to think about.